# Find two numbers that equal to target value

Tags: python

### Background

Given some random array of numbers like `[3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6]` and a target value `10`, find two numbers within the array that equal to the target value.

### Code

```
def two_Number_Sum(array, target):
    unique_number_set = set()
    for num in array:
        required_value = target - num
        if required_value in unique_number_set:
            return [num, required_value]
        else:
            unique_number_set.add(num)
    return []

print(two_Number_Sum([3, 5, -4, 8, 11, 1, -1, 6], 10))
```

I am wondering if I can make this answer more pythonic. I don't have a Python background so a lot of times I write code like Java or another language, and I figure it will be good practice to critique myself and write code that is more pythonic so it becomes natural.

Comment: `two_Number_Sum` should be wrritten as `two_number_sum`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few suggestions:

- **Naming**: `array` is not an array, a more appropriate name can be `numbers`. Also `unique_number_set` can be just `unique_numbers`, the name already tells that there are no duplicates.
- **Unnecessary else**: the `else` is not required so it can be removed.
- **Type hints**: @Linny already pointed this out. I add that, if the result doesn't need to be modified, consider returning a tuple. Additionally, it tells the caller that the result will only contain two numbers.

```py
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

def two_number_sum(numbers: List[int], target: int) -> Union[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[()]]:
    unique_numbers = set()
    for num in numbers:
        required_value = target - num
        if required_value in unique_numbers:
            return num, required_value
        unique_numbers.add(num)
    return ()
```

Thanks to @KellyBundy and @AJNeufeld for the feedbacks in the comments.

Comment: Your return type is wrong. `()`  is not a `Tuple[int,int]`.  You'd need `Union[Tuple[int,int], Tuple[]]`.  Alternately, return `None` and use `Optional[Tuple[int,int]]`.  Or, keep the return type and raise an exception if no pair can be found.

Comment: @AJNeufeld thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Just curious what does "Union" indicate? Does it mean that the return type can either be an empty tuple or a tuple with int,int?

Comment: @Dinero yes. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `itertools.combinations`. A lot of the pythonic code you will see is just clever use of built-in functions and libraries. Getting familiar with these will greatly speed up your learning of this language :).

```
import itertools
from typing import List

def two_number_sum_2(array: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for x, y in itertools.combinations(array, 2):
        if x + y == target:
            return [x, y]
```

It's shorter, cleaner, and is faster than your original code (faster with small datasets). A couple more tips:

- Functions and variables should be `snake_case`, not `Snake_Case` or `camel_Snake_Case`.
- Add type hints to display what types you accept as parameters, and what value you return from the function.

Comment: That helps and is there a way to make it more pythonic without using built-in functions? I think in a typical interview you can't use built-in functions.

Comment: Why using `itertools.combinations` is faster than OP's solution?

Comment: @Marc, perhaps it's faster when you include programmer time and CPU time...

Comment: This is a very common interview question, if you were to answer with a solution that generates all combinations without solid reasoning this is going to reflect badly. For large input the `O(N)` by OP is going to outperform this `O(N^2)` solution.

Comment: @Marc For the tests I ran my solution was faster, but I can see with bigger data sets my solution is considerably slower. I'll leave this answer here because it can still be a viable alternative when dealing with small datasets.